# typescript say to all public variables "undefined"

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, typescript

I got the following code

```
module Absence {
export var instance: AbsenceViewModel;


export class ViewModel {

    public items: KnockoutObservableArray<AbsenceItem>;


    public reloadData() {
            this.items.removeAll();
    }
  }
}
```

In my page I create an instance by using this

```
Absence.instance = new Absence.AbsenceViewModel();
```

Now when I call

```
Absence.instance.reloadData();
```

it say in the browser console

> Cannot read property 'removeAll' of undefined

But I imported my knockout library and the other needed stuff. So it is present.

When I use internal the instance like

```
Absence.instance.items.removeAll();
```

What do I wrong?

**Edit:**

I wrote the dcklaration of the viewModel and the declaration of the instance in a separate JS file. These files are loaden in the page. After the page is ready I instantiate the instance of the `ViewModel` by hand in the debug console. In this I call the method `reloadData`. So that I can be sure that all classes are available at the moment when I call the methods.

Comment: It's impossible to say without seeing where you're initializing `instance` and what triggers that. But fundamentally, the issue is most likely that you're trying to use `Absence.instance.reloadData()` *before* you've done `Absence.instance = new ...` Use the debugger built into your browser to find out.

Comment: Sorry, I have added the information. I create these first manually in the console. So the classes exists. I create the instance myself and call after that the method myself.

Comment: @Sascha: Where do you initialize `items`? (e.g. `items = new KnockoutObservableArray<AbsenceItem>()`? If you don't, that's probably the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not yet familiar with the `get` mechanism in TypeScript, so while you were able to solve your issue with it, I'm adding this as another answer, which I believe is the general solution to tackling this problem.

The following error:

> Cannot read property 'removeAll' of undefined

Is caused by the fact you do not initialize the `items`array. You have only declared it as a property of your `ViewModel` class. Adding a constructor and initlaizing your properties in a correct manner avoids these kind of issues. Hence, update your code to:

```
module Absence {
export var instance: AbsenceViewModel;


export class ViewModel {

    public items: KnockoutObservableArray<AbsenceItem>;

    constructor(){
        this.items = ko.observableArray();
    }

    public reloadData() {
            this.items.removeAll();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. 
I must create a getter to access to the property.

```
 get elements(): KnockoutObservableArray<AbsenceItem> {
        return this.items;
    }
```

After that I can to following

```
public reloadData() {
   this.elements.removeAll();
}
```

That helped for me